# Calculating Distance using lat,long between other cities and user selected city

Tags: mysql, spatial

I am looking to calculate the distance between two lat,long based on user search. for example if user is searching for "Athens" in the below table then I have to calculate the distance of Athens from other cities in the list.

```
State   City         lat    long
NY  Holtsville  40.813078   -73.046388
NY  Brunswick   40.813223   -73.049288
MA  Agawam      42.071523   -72.624257
FL  Minneola    28.577556   -86.818296
GA  Athens      33.903503   -83.318464
AL  Graysville  33.621087   -86.958247
```

I know we can use st_distance_sphere(POINT({long1}, {lat1}), POINT({long2}, {lat2}))

So basically I'm looking a select query to get the lat,long of city Athens and then using st_distance_sphere formula i need to calculate the distance of other cities

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply distance formula in your SQL Query to find distance between two given coordinates.

```
select
    2 * 3961 * asin(sqrt((sin(radians((lat2 - lat1) / 2))) ^ 2 + cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * (sin(radians((lon2 - lon1) / 2))) ^ 2)) as distance
from
    the_data;
```

lat2 and lat1 is the coordinate between which you want to find distance the_data is the table name from where you are getting values.
Here is few links which will help you to understand how does it works

[Calculate distance between Lat/Lng points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

[Mysql Query Explanation of Distance Formula](http://daynebatten.com/2015/09/latitude-longitude-distance-sql/)